# cant connect to mysql - Error with Set up of Laravel 5.8 with PHP 7.1 on InMotion hosting. Multi php versions

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I can't seem to get laravel to connect to MySQL using **PHP 7.1** and **laravel 5.8**

**Error:**

> Illuminate \ Database \ QueryException could not find driver (SQL:
>   select * from `users`

I didn't have this issue using **php 5.6** and **laravel 5.4** but I'd rather use the new versions!

I did:

```
composer update

composer require doctrine/dbal
```

and included `extension=pdo_mysql.so` in **php.ini**
as well as **restart apache**

Comment: ok so details.   this is a multi php setup at Inmotion hosting.   maybe I have to install something, pdo?   been using php 5.6 and now I want to use 7.1 for a specific site.

Comment: did you check your php version in the server?

Comment: yes. 


PHP 7.1.30 (cli) (built: Jul 23 2019 18:47:44) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.1.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.1.30, Copyright (c) 1999-2018, by Zend Technologies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok this is fixed:

The server's PHP configuration has been switched to the Apache MPM to "Event" rather than "Prefork" as Prefork is typically only needed on non-FPM servers running Opcache.

also enabled FPM on my site running php 7.1 as it is typically required when running Opcache on separate PHP versions.